# How do I clear the MySQL Query Planner's statistics

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a number of complex queries that I'm trying to benchmark. It was discovered that on one production box that the query planner hadn't been updated which is likely the cause of some of the poor performance we were seeing (MyISAM tables). To be clear, all indexes on the table are showing with NULL cardinality.

Of course, I need to perform an ANALYZE TABLE on my production boxes, but I'd like to somehow benchmark the performance of my queries in a dev environment before I do that. My dev environment shows good, usable indexes on the table. I'd like to.. "UNANALYZE" the table so I can compare the performance of the broken indexes we have in production versus what we should expect with proper indexes. Would  just deleting the index give me the same results, or is there a better way to just flush the statistics?

BTW, I recognize that the NULL cardinality is an obvious problem and easy to fix. However, I'd like to quantify how much this has been hurting the performance. You know.. for science!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not, AFAIK, but you could play with FORCE_INDEX() clause on your SQL statement to force usage of an inadequate index, and then MySQL will fallback to table scan ;)